# Showing a DIV if a checkbox is UNchecked

Tags: jquery

I am trying to show a div if a checkbox is unchecked, and hide if it is checked. I have this, but I seem to be missing something:

http://jsfiddle.net/XyUWV/8/

HTML:

```
<input name="billing_check" id="billing_check" type="checkbox" class="billing_check" size="40"  checked="checked"/>

<div class="registration_box01 showme">
          <div class="title">
            <h4>billing information - infomration associated with your credit card<br />
            </h4>
          </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("input[name='billing_check']").change(function() {
  (".showme").toggle($("input[name='mycheckboxes']:checked").length>0);
});
```

Style:

```
.showme{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: *"I seem to be missing something"*: The `$` before `(".showme")` ? Also your fiddle does not use jQuery but Mootools.

Comment: Like Felix Kling said, you need to set `$` before a jQuery function. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12092794/1250044

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be checking against the wrong checkbox, should `mycheckboxes` be `billing_check`. Also, instead of `.length`, you could check against `.is(':checked')`, like this:

```
$('#billing_check').change(function() {     
    $('.showme').toggle(!$(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

### [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GeekyEggo/XyUWV/13/)

Answer (score 1):

Like Felix Kling said, you need to set $ before a jquery function. But the main mistake was the false input name `mycheckboxes` name it to `billing_check` will work.

**HTML**

```
<input name="billing_check" id="billing_check" type="checkbox" class="billing_check" size="40"  checked="checked"/>

<div class="registration_box01 showme">
  <div class="title">
    <h4>billing information - infomration associated with your credit card<br />
    </h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

​

**CSS**

```
.showme{
    display:none;
}
```

​

**JS**

```
$('#billing_check').change(function() {     
    $('.registration_box01').toggle(!$(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

​

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/XyUWV/19/)**

Answer (score 0):

I'd reference that checkbox by id, and use .is(":checked")

http://jsfiddle.net/XyUWV/12/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, though not tested

```
$("#billing_check").click(function()
{
    if(this.checked)
    {
        $(".registration_box01").hide();
    }else
    { 
        $(".registration_box01").show();
   }
});
```